# Temporally share of category by timestamps using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Lets say we have a changing object with timestamps for each state resulting in the following DataFrame:

```
id  category timestamp
0   A        2022-10-04T00:00:00.000Z   
1   B        2022-10-04T02:00:00.000Z
2   C        2022-10-04T10:00:00.000Z
3   A        2022-10-04T11:00:00.000Z
4   B        2022-10-04T12:00:00.000Z
```

How to get the temporally shares of id 0-3 `category` using the timestamps:

```
A: 3h / 0.2500
B: 8h / 0.6667
C: 1h / 0.0833
```

Comment: I would like to know, how long did the object stay in the given states. The disired result is in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        "category": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B"],
        "timestamp": [
            "2022-10-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "2022-10-04T02:00:00.000Z",
            "2022-10-04T10:00:00.000Z",
            "2022-10-04T11:00:00.000Z",
            "2022-10-04T12:00:00.000Z",
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Change dtype
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

# Evaluate delta between rows
df["delta"] = df["timestamp"].shift(-1).dt.hour - df["timestamp"].dt.hour
df["delta"] = df["delta"].fillna(0)

# Sum results and get percentages
df = (
    df.groupby("category")["delta"]
    .agg(sum)
    .reset_index()
    .assign(perc=lambda df_: df_["delta"] / df_["delta"].sum())
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
  category  delta      perc
0        A    3.0  0.250000
1        B    8.0  0.666667
2        C    1.0  0.083333
```